# How to use bootstrap has-success and has-error in textbox in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use `has-success` and `has-error` in textbox. If textbox is empty then it should display `X` icon on right side in the textbox and the same way on success. Currently, icon is displaying outside.
[image]

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="has-success input-group">                             
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: The `has-success` goes in the outer div

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please provide me an answer for this and also the icon is not attached with the textbox

Comment: Is [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yLUvYS) what you want it to look like?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want something like shown in the image. But in shown image, icon should attach with textbox.

Comment: Which is want the fiddle shows - what do you want to change in the fiddle?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, In the fiddle, icon is inside the textbox but I want this icon attached with textbox

Comment: I tested your code in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GntuSJ) and worked with inline `<span>`. Are you have other CSS class which affects inline styling, and use validation which shows `has-success` if `TextBoxFor` value is not empty?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, No I am not using any other `CSS` except bootstrap. If you allow me then I will share you my `_Layout`.